# Waiting for a person in German

Tags: preposition, grammar-identification

In English we say,

> To wait for someone

In German we say,

> Auf jemanden warten

Why we use "auf" rather than "fuer" here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because it's a different language. Especially with phrasal verbs, prepositions are completely arbitrary both in English and German.

The main point why German uses *auf* with many phrasal verbs is that this preposition cannot be mistaken as an adverbial in most contexts because it means *on/onto*. That relation is rare.

Consider:

> Er wartet für seinen Freund auf das Paket.

That means that he stays at home waiting for the parcel instead of the friend. He does this as a friendly turn **for his friend**.

> He waits for the parcel for his friend.

In English, you had to guess that from context.

Comment: Some varieties of English use "on", so German is not an outlier. See [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wait_on) definitions 2 & 3.

Answer (score 0):

Because für implies that I am doing something for (in the meaning of instead of or for the benefit of) someone.

Comment: How does this compare with in English?